# Network Engineering Canonical Questions or FAQ

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Our sister site, Server Fault, has a wiki of “[canonical questions](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1986/what-are-the-canonical-answers-weve-discovered-over-the-years/1987#1987)” that provide comprehensive answers to the most-often asked questions.  We decided to create a similar list of questions and answers for Network Engineering.  The questions and answers provide a single resource that visitors and members alike can get their most common questions answered.

To that end, I’ve compiled a list of questions that cover the most popular topics on Network Engineering.  This is just my opinion, so feel free to recommend other questions (or categories) to be included.

**OSI and TCP/IP Models**

[OSI Model and Networking Protocols Relationship](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/osi-model-and-networking-protocols-relationship)

[What is a "Layer 3 Switch"?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24432/what-is-a-layer-3-switch)

[OSI layer : Ethernet and IP address](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19409/osi-layer-ethernet-and-ip-address)

[Do OSI and TCP/IP models use the same protocols?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52298/do-osi-and-tcp-ip-models-use-the-same-protocols)

[Where do the layers of the OSI Model operate in the operating system?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22650/where-do-the-layers-of-the-osi-model-operate-in-the-operating-system)?

**Cabling (copper and fiber optics)**

[Is 30 Mbit/s fibre faster than 30 Mbit/s copper?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48526/is-30-mbit-s-fibre-faster-than-30-mbit-s-copper)

[Speed benefits when switching from 1Gb copper LAN to Fiber Optic](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45885/speed-benefits-when-switching-from-1gb-copper-lan-to-fiber-optic)

[What's the difference between an Ethernet cable and a UTP cable?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10870/whats-the-difference-between-an-ethernet-cable-and-a-utp-cable)

[Minimum Ethernet Cable Length?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7483/minimum-ethernet-cable-length)

[The maximum length of CAT6 for intranet network?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42696/the-maximum-length-of-cat6-for-intranet-network)

[When to choose fiber instead of twisted pair (copper)](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99/when-to-choose-fiber-instead-of-twisted-pair-copper)

[Multi-Mode and Single-Mode Fiber Differences](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/493/multi-mode-and-single-mode-fiber-differences)

[Speed of Light in Copper VS Fiber - Why is Fiber Better?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16438/speed-of-light-in-copper-vs-fiber-why-is-fiber-better)

**Ethernet**

[Why do we still use Ethernet?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/why-do-we-still-use-ethernet)

[Does having a longer Ethernet cable slow your connection?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34117/does-having-a-longer-ethernet-cable-slow-your-connection)

[Why was the MTU size for ethernet frames calculated as 1500 bytes?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2962/why-was-the-mtu-size-for-ethernet-frames-calculated-as-1500-bytes)

[Jumbo Ethernet Frame Deployment](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/jumbo-ethernet-frame-deployment)

**Wireless**

[Is it safe to use any wifi channel in the 2.4GHz band?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6938/is-it-safe-to-use-any-wifi-channel-in-the-2-4ghz-band)

[How do you prevent rogue wireless access points on a network?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123/how-do-you-prevent-rogue-wireless-access-points-on-a-network)

[Why does WLAN use Collision Avoidance and not Collison detection?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10715/why-does-wlan-use-collision-avoidance-and-not-collison-detection)

[How does a WiFi range extender work?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13216/how-does-a-wifi-range-extender-work)

[omnidirectional antennas and the dipole antenna](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/327/omnidirectional-antennas-and-the-dipole-antenna)

[Wireless Controller based vs Non-controller based](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/wireless-controller-based-vs-non-controller-based)

**MAC (Layer 2) Addressing**

[How does a switch learn a switch table?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13012/how-does-a-switch-learn-a-switch-table)

[Why does ipv6 specify 128 bit address, when there are only 48 bits in MAC addresses?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/why-does-ipv6-specify-128-bit-address-when-there-are-only-48-bits-in-mac-addres)

[Reason for both a MAC and an IP address](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3329/reason-for-both-a-mac-and-an-ip-address)

[Does the source MAC address of a frame change when it passes through several switches?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/28329/does-the-source-mac-address-of-a-frame-change-when-it-passes-through-several-swi)

**VLANS and Trunking**

[Introductory level explanation of VLANs](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/732/introductory-level-explanation-of-vlans)

[Why and how are Ethernet Vlans tagged?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-and-how-are-ethernet-vlans-tagged)

[Difference between Subnet and VLAN?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/difference-between-subnet-and-vlan)

**IP Addressing**

[How do you calculate the prefix, network, subnet, and host numbers?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers)

[Why do we need IPv6?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24132/why-do-we-need-ipv6)

[What stops someone from configuring their network with IP addresses they do not own?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56208/what-stops-someone-from-configuring-their-network-with-ip-addresses-they-do-not)

[Why are there 3 ranges of private IPv4 addresses?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32119/why-are-there-3-ranges-of-private-ipv4-addresses)

**TCP/UDP**

[Why do we need a 3-way handshake? Why not just 2-way?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24068/why-do-we-need-a-3-way-handshake-why-not-just-2-way)

[Why only port 80 for web services?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1976/why-only-port-80-for-web-services)

[PING port number?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37896/ping-port-number)

[What do TCP/UDP add to "raw ip"?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27830/what-do-tcp-udp-add-to-raw-ip)

**QoS**

[Are CoS and QoS ever interchangeable?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53/are-cos-and-qos-ever-interchangeable)

[Implementing Cisco QoS model to end users](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42660/implementing-cisco-qos-model-to-end-users)