# What should we have in NE "How to Ask" box?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am concerned about how unfriendly it seems to new users that we invite them to **Ask a Question** but don't put helpful information next to them when they do.

It turns out that Stack Exchange has two features we can make use of to help immediately:

- We can customise the "How to Ask" box
- We can put triggers for particular keywords

[image]

I have put as an answer my proposal.

All suggestions and observations gratefully received.

Comment: I think we need to do that with more tags, for example [tag:subnet]. We could then point to [Network Engineering Canonical Questions or FAQ](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/848/8499). Also, would could work the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) into the first part of what you are proposing.

Answer (score 7):

### How to Ask

I think something like:

> **Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about
>
>   professionally managed networks in a business environment.**
>
> *(Note: All questions about RESIDENTIAL/HOME networking and
>
>   CONSUMER-grade equipment, are explicitly **OFF**-topic.)*
>
> **On-Topic** subjects include<sup>*****</sup>:
>
> - List of a *few* common on-topic subjects
>
> **Off-Topic** subjects include<sup>*****</sup>:
>
> - List of a *few* common off-topic subjects
>
> <sup>*****</sup>For more details, please see our [What topics can I
>   ask about
>   here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
>   page.
>
> To help guide you to ask a better question that can get a good answer
>   in less
>   time, we have put together the [Network Engineering Question
>   Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499).
>
> Questions about this web site should be asked on [Network Engineering
>   Meta](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/),
>   and many answers about this web site can be found on our [Help Center](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help).
>
> Discussions and other off-topic subjects should be discussed on
>   [General Network Engineering
>   Recommendations](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations).

---

### Trigger Tags

For the Trigger Tags, I think it could be greatly simplified. Since it is set up to link to something else, I would propose we get together a list of tags covered by the [Network Engineering Canonical Questions or FAQ](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/848/8499) (this may also be subject to expansion), then we could have a single message for when one of those tags is chosen.

Something like:

> Many questions asked for this tag are closed as duplicates.
>   In order
>   to prevent your question from being closed as a duplicate,
>   please
>   review the
>
> [Network Engineering Canonical Questions or
>   FAQ](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/848/8499)
>
> to see if one of the canonical questions already answers your
>   question.
>
> Also, please perform a search on the main site to see if your question
>   has already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 4):

The following is a first-cut proposal for what we should do.  All suggestions and comments gratefully received.

## How to Ask

We currently have a completely generic "How to Ask" box, which I think is unhelpful.

**I propose:**

> Network Engineering is for professional networks
>
> **On Topic** questions include
>
> - Configuration of professional switches, routers, firewalls etc
> - Protocol theory and network design
> - Networking tools
> - **For networks under your direct control**
>
> **Off Topic** Subjects include
>
> - Layer 4 or above protocols, such as HTTP (perhaps Super User)
> - Consumer networking (perhaps Super User)
> - Server configuration (perhaps Server Fault)
> - Homework problems (because it doesn't help you if we answer)
> - Bypassing security (The one who pays for the network chooses its rules)
> - Product and resource recommendations (but welcome in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=networkengineering.stackexchange.com))
>
> For more details, please see our [On Topic](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page

Just for reference, this is what they did at [Mathematica](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1813/our-how-to-ask-sidebar).

---

## Trigger Tags

We can have "trigger tags", which make text pop up if the tag is selected

**Propose that [network-mask](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network-mask) triggers:**

> We get many IPv4 subnet mask questions
>
> - Want to understand IP addresses and masks? See LINK
> - Want to understand "slash notation" like `/24`? See LINK
> - Want to understand the binary maths? see LINK
> - Want to know what mask corresponds to `/X`? See LINK
> - Want to divide a `/X` into `/Y` and `/Z`? See LINK
> - Want to know how many hosts fit in a `/X`?  See LINK
> - Want to know special address `192.168.X.Y`., `172.16.X.Y` and `10.X.Y.Z`?  See LINK
> - Want to know about all the other special addresses?  See LINK
> - All our network mask questions are collected at LINK

**Propose that [dhcp](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dhcp) triggers**

> We get many DHCP questions, many of which are duplicates.
>
> - Want to know about DHCP broadcasts? See LINK
> - Want to know about DHCP relays?  See LINK

For reference, this is what they did for "what font is this?" questions at [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2353/do-we-want-tag-alerts-for-font-identification-and-critique-questions-and-how-sho).